# Issue in uploading file/image on KitKat

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, androidhttpclient

Does anyone here know a way to upload an image from android 4.4 KitKat to a web server?
I have tried multipart file upload and also Base64, but none of them seems to work.
I have looked all over the internet but no luck.

Here is the code that is working until JellyBean:

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
    String upLoadServerUri = "http://hentairandom.com/el/files/try/uploader.php";
    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null; 
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File Does not exist");
        return 0;
    }

    try { // open a URL connection to the Servlet
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
        conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
        conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // create a buffer of  maximum size
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // read file and write it into form...
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); 

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);              
        }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

        Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
        if(serverResponseCode == 200){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tv2.setText("File Upload Completed.");
                    Toast.makeText(SecondUpload.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });               
        }   

        //close the streams //
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) { 
        dialog.dismiss(); 
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(SecondUpload.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        dialog.dismiss(); 
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(SecondUpload.this, "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e); 
    }
    dialog.dismiss();      
    return serverResponseCode; 
}
```

Comment: It certainly can be done, please review other posts on the site and if you can't find your answer post your code.

Comment: I tried everywhere but i could not find a solution. im about to post my code as an answer, it worked for me till android jellybean

Comment: you should probably be more specific about the problem you are having. What does "none of them seems to work" mean specifically?

Comment: none of the solutions i have found over the internet worked on kitkat.

Comment: you should probably be more specific about the problem you are having. ;-). Indeed. You did not tell what exactly does not work. Much to vague. Come to the point. Where does it go wrong? Errors. Exceptions. Logcat.

Comment: I did not change anything in my code for kitkat. Not with multipart and not with base64. So this is very unusual.